# Maven Dependencies for Jersey @Context

Tags: jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I am trying to get the `HttpServletRequest` from a jersey `ContainerRequestFilter`, using `@Context` as follows:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class MyFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    protected HttpServletRequest httpRequest;

    @Override
    public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest containerRequest) {
       // logic ...
    }

}
```

The filter is invoked upon the incoming request, but `httpRequest` is always null.

Currently am using version 1.19.3 for both `jersey-server` and `jersey-json`. Am trying to move to a later version of jersey to see if this solves the issue.
Have changed the `jersey-server` version to 2.7, however there is no corresponding `jersey-json` with the same version. Instead, am bringing in the dependency for `jersey-media-json-jackson` version 2.8, as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <exclusions>   <exclusion>
    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
    <groupId>asm</groupId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8</version>
</dependency>
```

However, this throws the following build error (same when using `jersey-json` version 1.19.3):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

What are the correct jersey dependencies which are required for `@Context` to successfully inject the `HttpServletRequest` object into the filter?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The annotation `@Context` is part of

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I am still using Jersey version 2.23.1 and `@Context` works fine. The lastest version is 2.26, which is probably the version you should start with.

You are probably looking for a library to serialise and deserialise JSON:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

These are all my Jersey dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-declarative-linking</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I have the dependency for @Context. My question is: what are the addition Jersey dependencies and their versions (apart from jersey-server). Thanks very much!